# EnableWebMvcConfiguration required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having the error below when I attempt to create a second table in my database directly from my project:

> EnableWebMvcConfiguration required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory'
>   that could not be found.

I've tried many different solutions on google with no success I hope you experts can help me fix this issue

Here is my Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String employees(Model model){

        List<Worker> employees = employeeService.getAllWorkers();

        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Worker());
        model.addAttribute("title", "employees"); //Tab title
        model.addAttribute("isAdd", true);
        return "workers";
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute Worker worker, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        Worker dbWorker = employeeService.save(worker);
        return null;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_worker?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&serverTimezone=America/New_York
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=Select 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.madcoderz</groupId>
    <artifactId>studentaccounts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>studentaccountsapp</name>
    <description>Student Accounts App</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

MainClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.madcoderz.studentaccountsapp.repository"})
public class StudentAccountsApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentAccountsApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you have double `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in your pom?

Comment: How are you defining your entities and repositories look up? Also, can you post your entity class?

Comment: The problem i had was a Renaming issue. What i did was to write all by myself and now it is working as it should.